# change RichTexteditor background color

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I am using Flex 4.5, and i am trying to change the back ground color of richtexteditor but i am not able to do so in flex 4.5 but its working fine in flex 3.

Please Help Me,

Thank You,

Comment: How are you setting the color at this moment?

Comment: RichTextEditor is an mx component. It has no explicit Spark (Flex 4.x) counterpart so there should be no difference. Are you setting the background color in the exact same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use contentBackgroundColor property instead of backgroundColor.

```
<mx:RichTextEditor id="myRTE" text="Congratulations" contentBackgroundColor="red"/>
```